# Why am i getting a syntax error after defining a function?

Tags: python

I have this code to define a function

```
def f(Frequency,Omegahot,Beta,Omegacold,Thot,Tcold):
    C=300000000
    k=1.38E-23
    h=6.062E-34
    return(Omegahot*numpy.power(Frequency,Beta))*((2*h*numpy.power(Frequency,3)/(C**2)))*(1/(numpy.exp(h*Frequency/(k*Thot))-1)) + (Omegacold*numpy.power(Frequency,Beta)*((2*h*numpy.power(Frequency,3)/(C**2)))*(1/(numpy.exp(h*Frequency/(k*Tcold))-1))

xdata=[1,2,3,4,5]   
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f,xdata,fluxs,p0=None,)
print popt
```

But i get a syntax error at the line xdata=[1,2,3,4,5] what am i doing wrong

Comment: [PEP-8 recommends limiting a single line to 79 characters long.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) You should consider splitting up your massive equation into multiple lines with some temporary variables to make it more readable, and make errors like this easier to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parenthesis on the previous line are not balanced, adding one more at the end fixes that

```
return (Omegahot*numpy.power(Frequency,Beta))*((2*h*numpy.power(Frequency,3)/(C**2)))*(1/(numpy.exp(h*Frequency/(k*Thot))-1)) + (Omegacold*numpy.power(Frequency,Beta)*((2*h*numpy.power(Frequency,3)/(C**2)))*(1/(numpy.exp(h*Frequency/(k*Tcold))-1)))
```

but the formula is a little bit of a mess to figure out *where* they really belong.

You really want to split up that formula into something fitting within an 80 character line and using temporary variables:

```
temp1 = Omegahot * numpy.power(Frequency, Beta)
temp2 = 2 * h * numpy.power(Frequency, 3) / (C ** 2)
temp3 = 1 / (numpy.exp(h * Frequency / (k * Thot)) - 1)
temp4 = Omegacold * numpy.power(Frequency, Beta) *
temp5 = 1 / (numpy.exp(h * Frequency / (k * Tcold)) - 1)
return (temp1 * temp2 * temp3) + (temp4 * temp2 * temp6)
```

but with better variable names. I already managed to cut out a repeated `temp2` from the formula just by factoring this out into smaller chunks.

Comment: yer that fixed it guess trying to do short cuts and copy it from somewhere else never really works

Answer (score 0):

Readability counts. Here is one way to rewrite your function which is more readable. By pre-computing expressions that appear more than once, you will need fewer levels of parentheses and also make the computation complete a tad faster.

```
import numpy as np
def f(Frequency, Omegahot, Beta, Omegacold, Thot, Tcold, exp=np.exp, power=np.power):
    C = 300000000
    k = 1.38E-23
    h = 6.062E-34
    fb = power(Frequency, Beta)
    f3 = power(Frequency, 3)
    C2 = C ** 2
    C3 = fb * 2 * h * f3 / C2
    hF = h * Frequency
    return ((Omegahot * C3 / (exp(hF / (k * Thot)) - 1))
            + (Omegacold * C3 / (exp(hF / (k * Tcold)) - 1))))
```